# Nginx location regex is not matching

Tags: nginx, regex

The following has been working to cache css and js for me:

```
location ~ "^(.*)\.(min.)?(css|js)$" {
    expires max;
}
```

results:

```
$ curl -I http://mysite.com/test.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 18:55:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 19578
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jan 2014 18:54:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
X-Backend: stage01
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I am trying to get versioning setup for my js / css using a 10 digit unix timestamp and am having issues getting a regex match with the following valid a regex.

```
location ~ "^(.*)([\d]{10})\.(min\.)?(css|js)$" {
    expires max;
}
```

results:

```
$ curl -I http://mysite.com/test_1234567890.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 19:05:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 19578
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jan 2014 18:54:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-Backend: stage01
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: Try to run nginx in debug mode, you will certainly see reg_exp match or not, You also need provide us full nginx.conf, because some other rules can be triggered earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I would try it without the brackets around \d, brackets are normally used for either contiguous characters or numbers, your brackets say match either character '\' or 'd'

```
"^(.*)(\d{10})\.(min\.)?(css|js)$"
```

Also, are you specifically saving the group info that you're capturing inside the parens?

For clarity on the comments below.

Start simple.

```
"^.*[0-9]*\.css$"

"^.*[:digit:]*\.css$"

"^.*\d*\.css$"
```

Depending on which works, use that base for the digits and expand as below.

```
"^.*\d{10}\.(min\.)?(css|js)$"
```

If you're matching the http/https as well, you can start it with the http/s stuff below, remember to change to which ever digit notation worked.

```
"^http(s)?://.*[0-9]{10}\.(min\.)?(css|js)$"
```

Comment: still not working without the square brackets, I am currently not using the info I am capturing

Comment: Are you matching on the http string? And are you just looking for a string containing the ten digits and css/js ending?

Comment: Yse, this is a location block that is included in a server declaration. I am looking for a 10 digit number in the name ending in .css, .js, .min.css or .min.js

Comment: If the 10 digits will always be before the ending, ie 1234567890.css

then one of these should work

"^http(s)?://.*\d{10}\.(css|js)$"
"^http(s)?://.*[0-9]{10}\.(css|js)$"
"^http(s)?://.*[:digit:]{10}\.(css|js)$"
"^http(s)?://.*\d+\.(css|js)$"


Should match. If you're having problems build from what you know works.

For instance, with the above URL 'http://mysite.com/test_1234567890.css'

Does '.*\d*\.css' Work?

Comment: @rfelsburg, i'm not sure why you claim that `[:digit:]*` is going to match anything of interest, the docs say it should be more like `[[:digit:]]*`, if anything.  http://mdoc.su/o/re_format.7

Comment: @cnst First off, don't be an ass.

Secondly, You don't use two brackets unless you're trying to match a null expression at the beginning/end. If you read the posix page you just posted, you'll see where it states under character classes:

     Within a bracket expression, the name of a character class enclosed in
     `[:' and `:]' stands for the list of all characters belonging to that
     class.

Comment: @rfelsburg, go ahead, provide wrong solutions, and call people names who point out your mistakes.  `echo 111 | sed -E "s#[[:digit:]]#a#g"`

Comment: Again, did you actually look at the documentation you provided? I don't know how it's my mistake, when the example I pulled at the bottom was word for word form the page you submitted.

Comment: @rfelsburg: Those docs - and your quote - say that you can use e.g. `[:digit:]` **within a bracket expression** i.e. use it like `[[:digit:]]`. The outer set is the bracket-expression, the inner set is the character-class.